# The repeating of "and" in regular expression

Tags: regex

I find from some sources that "and" can be done as `(?=R1)(?=R2).*` However, I want a regular expression that can match string which matches repeating of both R1 and R2, which is something like `((?=R1)(?=R2).*)*` but it apparently does not work. Any idea how to do it correctly? Or is it even possible?

For example, if I want a regex matching repeating concatenation of substring starting with 'a' and ending with 'b'. (I know we can do `(a.*b)*` but actual R1 and R2 are quite complicated.)

Comment: Please show some sample inputs, and also show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: Please specify the programming language you're using in the tags

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to find something like `R1R2` as well as `R2R1`, correct?

If so, you can try something like this:

```
(R[12]){2,}
```

Explanation:

- `(R[12])`: Find a group of R followed by either a 1 or a 2.
- `{2,}`: Find the previous group 2 or more times.

This means it will also find `R1R2R2R2R1R1R2R2R2` or any repeating pattern of R1 and R2.

Hope this helps!